# 2012 Honda Civic won't start - no power, no lights noting, tried jump start too

Tags: honda, battery, civic, no-crank-no-start

My 2012 Honda Civic is not starting, not dashboard lights nothing when I switch it on.

At first I tried to jump start the car however, nothing. Then I searched the internet and realized that this could happen only if my main fuse is broken. And yes, it was broken. So, I purchased the new one from dealership and replaced it.

Situation is very similar to this video and yes same fuse was broken but replacing didn't help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFFkZXtJ_LY

Still, the same. It's not starting. I checked the battery connection and it looks good. Batter is in good condition.

What could have happen? what should I do befoer I tow my car and take it mechnich which is gonna  put a big hole in my pocket.

Nothing starts.. No power

I took a car for a ride just a three days back before it's dead

I haven't checked the voltage yet..

I did jump start but not working? Should I put jump start for longer time.. I tried for 5 mins.

Battery is just 3 years old

**Update 1**

1. I realize when I first jump start my car i plugged wrong terminal (both the wires on my friends car was black and was no indication on battery so took the best guess, i was wrong)
2. So after changing the main fuse I called another friend with honda and did charge for 10 minutes.
3. Now I have my lights and horn back. however I see ABS, Battery and other warning lights on and when I try to start the car it cranks but doesn't start.

seems like other fuses are blown too. I am gonna check all the fuses today and see what else has blown. Hopefully haven't screw something big.

any suggestion ?

**Update 2:**
No other fuse is blown.. and whatever battery I charged yesterday is drained.. again no power, no lights, no horn nothing.

Comment: The big-wire battery connections can look good and be bad. Remove, clean, and reinstall _both_ ends of _both_  battery cables. A dirty or loose cable end is a common fault. Sometimes (but less often) the joints between the cable and the clamp are bad, but first try the end-of-cable connections.

Comment: I removed negative yesterday check all the connection and fit again... Let me do with positive terminal

Comment: I checked positive as well.. All the connection are good

Comment: The first step is to determine if the battery is in good condition and fully charged. Do the car's headlights illuminate at full brightness? Have you measured the battery's voltage? Have you charged it? How old is it? When did the engine last run?

Comment: How to charge a battery. I tried jump start but didn't work

Comment: To charge the battery, one uses a battery charger. Search online for "how to use automobile battery charger. " Another tactic is to find (borrow or buy) a battery of the same size that has been tested and was found healthy and charged, and install it in the car temporarily. When you have a known good battery in the car, you can continue to troubleshoot the starting system. Remember that just connecting a battery charger **does not mean the battery has accepted the charge, nor that the battery is healthy enough to run the starter and the motor's electrics.**

Comment: I realize i jump start wrong.. And that blow my main fuse.. Jump start correct after replacing the main fuse.. Now i see lights and horn but with lots of warning lights.. Still can't start my car

Comment: "Still can't start my car" is not clear. What happens when you turn the key? Does the starter motor crank the car's engine?

Comment: It cranks but doesn't start. I updated the question with udpate.

Answer (score 0):

This Answer assumes that the battery and starter motor are in good shape, and that the starter turns the engine over in a brisk and healthy fashion. If the cranking is sluggish, that needs to be addressed before continuing. If the cranking is brisk, then proceed onward:

The motor needs three things to run: spark, air, and fuel. Assuming that a bird hasn't built its nest in the air intake blocking the airflow, the motor will have air.

To diagnose further: turn the key so the starter cranks the car for a few seconds, then turn the key "off." Then remove one of the spark plugs. Is the plug tip wet or dry?

If the plug you removed has a dry tip, there's something wrong with the fuel system. The 21012 Civic has fuel injection, so the flaw could be either mechanical (something preventing fuel delivery, like a failed fuel pump) or electrical (something preventing the creation or transmission of the electrical signals that trigger the fuel injectors to open and pass fuel into the combustion chambers).

If the plug you removed has a wet tip, fuel is being delivered and there's something wrong in the ignition system: the electrical impulses provided to the spark plug gap that ignite the fuel/air mixture aren't being delivered to the spark plug.